# GLCD touchscreen interference with metal frame?

Tags: touchscreen, glcd

I am trying to use a 128x240 GLCD driven by t6963 and a resistive touchscreen. When touchscreen and the frame are far apart, everything goes well but when I put them together it starts sending touch signals. Should I use a spacer between them?

Comment: which micro controller are you using?

Comment: Did you try grounding the metal frame?

Comment: @Aug ATMega16 is the micro

Comment: @RonJ. Yes it is well grounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this problem arises when you use falling edge of you AVR micro for touch detection. Use Low level interrupt instead. This guarantees that the touch has lasted enough and removes the noise interferences

Comment: I set it to low level interrupt and now works fine. What was the reason?

Comment: I said in the answer, This makes sure that the interrupt lasts until the interrupt routine executed.